# sql query to find potential duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on employer's data to find out duplicate employers based on their names.

Data is Like this:

```
Employer ID   |   Legal Name   |    Operating Name
------------- | ---------------| --------------------
1             |      AA        |        AA
2             |      BB        |        AA
3             |      CC        |        BB
4             |      DD        |        DD
5             |      ZZ        |        ZZ
```

Now if I try to find all duplicates of employer AA the query should return the following result:

```
Employer ID   |   Legal Name   |    Operating Name
------------- | ---------------| --------------------
1             |      AA        |        AA
2             |      BB        |        AA
3             |      CC        |        BB
```

Employer 1's legal name and Employer 2's Operating Name are the direct match with the search.
But the catch is employer 3 which is not directly related with the search string but employer 2's legal name matches with employer 3's operating name.

And I need the search results up to nth level.  I am not sure if that can be achieved by recursive query of something like that.

Please help

I was trying to achieve this by Recursive CTE but then I realized that it is going into infinite recursion. Here is the code:

```
    DECLARE @SearchName VARCHAR(50)
    SET @SearchName = 'AA'
    ;With CTE_EmployerNames
    AS
    (
-- Anchor Member definition
select  * 
from    [dbo].[Name_Table]
where   Leg_Name = @SearchName 
OR      Op_Name = @SearchName 
UNION ALL
-- Recursive Member definition
select  N.*
from    [dbo].[Name_Table] N
JOIN    CTE_EmployerNames  C
ON      N.ID <> C.ID
AND     (N.Leg_Name = C.Leg_Name
OR      N.Leg_Name = C.Op_Name
OR      N.Op_Name = C.Leg_Name
OR      N.Op_Name = C.Op_Name)
    )

    select  * 
    from    CTE_EmployerNames
```

Update:
I created a stored procedure to achieve what I want. But this procedure is a bit slow because of looping and cursor. As of now this is solving my problem by little compromising with execution time. Any suggestion to optimize it or another way to do this will be highly appreciated. thanks guys. Here is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Similar_Name_Employers] 
@P_BaseName VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @Leg_Name VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Op_Name VARCHAR(50)

-- Create temp table to hold data temporarily
CREATE TABLE #Temp_Employers
(
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Leg_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Op_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Status] [bit] null -- To keep track if that record is processed or not
)

-- Insert all records which are directly matching with search criteria
INSERT INTO #Temp_Employers
SELECT  NT.ID, NT.Leg_Name, NT.Op_Name, 0
FROM    dbo.Name_Table NT
WHERE   NT.Leg_Name = @P_BaseName 
OR      NT.Op_Name = @P_BaseName 

while EXISTS (SELECT 1 from #Temp_Employers where Status = 0) -- until all rows are processed
BEGIN
    DECLARE @EmployerCursor CURSOR
    SET     @EmployerCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
    FOR
            SELECT  ID, Leg_Name, Op_Name  
            from    #Temp_Employers 
            where   Status = 0

    OPEN    @EmployerCursor

    FETCH   NEXT 
    FROM    @EmployerCursor
    INTO    @ID, @Leg_Name, @Op_Name

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        -- For every unprocessed record in temp table check if there is any possible duplicate.
        -- and insert all possible duplicate records in same table for further processing to find their possible duplicates     
        INSERT  INTO #Temp_Employers
        select  ID, Leg_Name, Op_Name, 0 
        from    dbo.Name_Table 
        WHERE   (Leg_Name = @Leg_Name 
        OR      Op_Name = @Op_Name 
        OR      Leg_Name = @Op_Name 
        OR      Op_Name = @Leg_Name)
        AND     ID NOT IN ( select  ID 
                            FROM    #Temp_Employers) 

        -- Update status of recently processed record to avoid processing again
        UPDATE  #Temp_Employers
        SET     Status = 1
        WHERE   ID = @ID

        FETCH   NEXT 
        FROM    @EmployerCursor
        INTO    @ID, @Leg_Name, @Op_Name
    END

    -- close cursor and deallocate memory
    CLOSE @EmployerCursor
    DEALLOCATE @EmployerCursor
END

select  ID,
        Leg_Name,
        Op_Name 
from    #Temp_Employers 
Order By ID

DROP TABLE #Temp_Employers 

END
```

Comment: Please include any attempts you've made to solve this on your own (if any) that show a decent effort was made to achieve your desired result set. If you haven't made any attempts of your own, consider doing some research, attempting to write a few queries, and return once you have something more to show. Questions asking someone to simply "Write me a query that does such-and-such" are likely to be closed.

Comment: Will you include the code for your best query so far?
The full answer to this depends on where you are starting from and the complexity of your data.
It's also very important to realize that, when attempting to find duplicates in data, you are actually moving into determining the PROBABILITY of duplicate data.
Having said the above you may be able to get by in the situation you describe with a self join. Here's a really rough (completely untested and likely in need of fixing) start: SELECT * FROM employers.e1 JOIN employers.e2 ON e1.OperatingName=e2.OperatingName
UNION (LegalName query)

Comment: Sorry guys I am new to this forum. I was trying to achieve this by Recursive CTE but then I realized that it is going into infinite recursion. I have added my question to include the code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two self joins.  I used `DISTINCT` to be safe - you don't need it for your example, but probably will for your actual data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.EMPID, T2.LEGAL_NAME, T.LEGAL_NAME
FROM TABLE T
INNER JOIN TABLE T2 ON T.LEGAL_NAME = T2.OPERATING_NAME
INNER JOIN TABLE T3 ON T2.OPERATING_NAME = T3.OPERATING_NAME
WHERE T.LEGAL_NAME <> T3.LEGAL_NAME
```

Rename and alias tables and columns as you like.

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07619/3/0)

**Edit - If you also want records where the op name is simply different from the legal name, `UNION` those in:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.EMPID, T2.LEGAL_NAME, T.LEGAL_NAME
FROM TABLE T
INNER JOIN TABLE T2 ON T.LEGAL_NAME = T2.OPERATING_NAME
INNER JOIN TABLE T3 ON T2.OPERATING_NAME = T3.OPERATING_NAME
WHERE T.LEGAL_NAME <> T3.LEGAL_NAME

UNION

SELECT EMPID, LEGAL_NAME, OP_NAME
FROM TABLE
WHERE LEGAL_NAME <> OP_NAME
```

[SQL Fiddle Example 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54494d/1/0)

Comment: It will not work if I have another record like: 7 | AA | KK

Comment: Ultimately I need to find out all possible duplicates by checking all names with all possible combinations.

Comment: @RakeshKumar I wouldn't think that record *should* show up.  So in that case, you also want records included that simply have a different op name than legal name?  Right now the logic is: show the record if it's op name is another record's legal name, then also show the record if is the base record for a duplication (in the example of 1|AA|AA, which by itself is correct)

Comment: @RakeshKumar See edit and second fiddle... For the record, in the first query, 7|AA|KK would show up, if KK was a legal named company.  Use the second query if you want it to show up either way.

Comment: Actually I need to find out all possible duplicates. Like if I search for AA then for sure first I want to list all the employers with AA as their Legal/Operating name. then if any of those employers have different Legal/Operating name then I want to include the possible duplicates of those names as well. And this should keep on searching in chain until I get all possible duplicates of AA

Comment: @RakeshKumar This query will do that.

Comment: Ok. Consider one example. How can I get all the possible duplicates of employer ZZ? I need to pass ZZ somewhere in the query right? Something like `where T.Legal_name = 'ZZ' or T.Operating_Name = 'ZZ'`

Comment: @RakeshKumar Yeah, exactly.  Mess around with the first SQL Fiddle link I provided.  ZZ would return nothing, since it is not duplicated in your example table.  `WHERE T.Legal_Name = 'AA'` would return the first two results (AA|AA, BB|AA), and adding `OR T.Operating_Name = 'AA'` would include the CC|BB record as you desire in your results.

Comment: @RakeshKumar It's easy to add records to the schema in SQL Fiddle (left side) to try other scenarios if you think there is one that won't return properly.

Comment: @RakeshKumar I added the 'AA' example for you here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07619/7/0

Comment: Yes that query have included CC|BB record as well but still it will return the possible duplicates up to 2 levels only. I have enhanced the table by adding few more possible duplicates of 'AA' and this query will not return all these records. Have a look at this sqlfiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db1401/1

Comment: @RakeshKumar I see...  Unfortunately my query is designed with the goal of returning all duplicates in mind.  If you remove the filter you will get all duplicates, but if you filter to AA you will only get duplicates that have a direct relation to AA.  I believe if you want a filter with *n* levels as you are describing, you will need to loop and cursor as you have.

Comment: Ultimately I need all possible potential duplicates at Nth level

Comment: Yes. That is what I thought. anyways thanks a lot for your efforts. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to build a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) in which the nodes are names and you want to find all the names that lead to your employee.

There is a beginning tutorial at *[Oracle Tip: Solving directed graph problems with SQL, part 1](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/oracle-tip-solving-directed-graph-problems-with-sql-part-1/)*, and a related StackOverflow question at *[Directed graph SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957486/directed-graph-sql)*.